# Pytorch fine tuned CNN model giving always the same prediction in training and validation data

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, imagenet

I decided to move from TensorFlow to Pytorch and I am with some issues in understanding how it works. I tried to follow [This Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html) which has a very simple example of Feature Extraction from ImegeNet CNNs for a binary classification problem.

In summary, in my code, the network is defined and called as follows

```
#Function for feature extraction
def set_parameter_requires_grad(model, feature_extracting):
    if feature_extracting:
        for param in model.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

# Initialize these variables which will be set in this if statement. Each of these
# variables is model specific.
def initialize_model(model_name, num_classes, feature_extract, use_pretrained):   

    model_ft = None
    input_size = 0

    if model_name == "resnet":
    """ Resnet18
    """
        if use_pretrained:
            model_ft = models.resnet18(weights="ResNet18_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1")
        else:
            model_ft = models.resnet18(weights=None)

        set_parameter_requires_grad(model_ft, feature_extract)
        num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
        model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
        input_size = 224

    return model_ft, input_size


model_ft, input_size = initialize_model("resnet", 2, feature_extract = True, use_pretrained = True)
```

The transforms I do in the data are defined below:

```
data_transforms = {
'train': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(input_size),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
]),
'val': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(input_size),
    transforms.CenterCrop(input_size),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
]),
```

}

I call the training this way:

```
if feature_extract:
    params_to_update = []

    for name, param in model_ft.named_parameters():
        if param.requires_grad:
            params_to_update.append(param)
            print("\t", name)
else:
    for name, param in model_ft.named_parameters():
        if param.requires_grad:
            print("\t", name)

# Observe that all parameters are being optimized
optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(params_to_update, lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
model_ft, hist = train_model(model_ft, dataloaders_dict, criterion, optimizer_ft, 
num_epochs=num_epochs, is_inception=(model_name == "inception"))
```

The model has 94% validation accuracy. After training, I save and load the model again.

```
# Save the model (SIMPLEST WAY)
print("save model the easiest way")
torch.save(model_ft, "MY_FIRST_TORCH_MODEL")
print("Load model the easiest way")
model = torch.load("MY_FIRST_TORCH_MODEL")
print("Evaluate model")
model.eval()
```

**So here it goes my problem:** I don't know how to process a testing data sample in order to make it be tested by the Pytorch model. I tried to load and test a training/validation sample just to be sure that the same accuracies in the training and test will also remain when I do a manual test. Here is what I did:

```
for name in os.listdir("./hymenoptera_data/train/bees/"):
    # testing one example image
    print("Predicting "+ "./hymenoptera_data/train/bees/"+name)
    img = cv2.imread("./hymenoptera_data/train/bees/"+name)
    img_to_test= cv2.resize(img, (224,224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    print(img_to_test.shape)
    img_to_test = img_to_test.astype('float32')

    test_x = img_to_test.reshape(1, 3, 224, 224)
    test_x = torch.from_numpy(test_x)

    output = model(test_x.cuda())
    pred = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)

    print(output)
    print(pred)
```

So, **no matter which sample I choose to test, the prediction is always the same**

What am I doing wrong here?

- Should the model be loaded in a different way?
- Is my function to test correct, especially considering that here I am doing feature extraction instead of fine tuning?
- Should I pre-process the data using the same transforms.compose function used to train and validate?
- What else should be added to test correctly an image given the example above?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, `img_to_test` is in the `HWC` format. You are reshaping the image when you should be transposing its axes from `HWC` to `CHW`. You may want to replace the following:

```
>>> test_x = img_to_test.reshape(1, 3, 224, 224)
```

With a call to [`np.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) or [`torch.transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html) instead:

```
>>> test_x = image_to_test.transpose(2,0,1).unsqueeze(0)
```

Comment: Did the following:

img = cv2.imread("./hymenoptera_data/train/bees/" + name)
img = img.astype('float32')
img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img = torch.from_numpy(img)
img_to_test=torch.transpose(img, 2, 0).unsqueeze(0), however, I still don't get the same accuracy in training.

Comment: should I have to divide my test data by 255 and subtract the mean of each channel too? how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

solved by doing the following:

```
#This transform is crucial to solve the problem. Apply it also for testing data

transform_norm = transforms.Compose([
transforms.Resize(224),
transforms.CenterCrop(224),
transforms.ToTensor(),
transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

predictions = []

for name in os.listdir("./hymenoptera_data/train/bees/"):
    # testing one example image
    print("Predicting "+ "./hymenoptera_data/train/bees/"+name)
    model.eval()

    img = Image.open("./hymenoptera_data/train/bees/" + name)
    
    # The transform_norm will already be used for converting PIL 
    # to tensor and also put the dimensions able to be used by Pytorch. 
    # I only add one dimension with unsqueeze(0)
    img_normalized = transform_norm(img).unsqueeze(0)

    #Lets go testing
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(img_normalized.cuda())
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        np_arr = preds.cpu().detach().numpy()
        predictions.append(np_arr)

predictions=np.array(predictions)
print(np.array(np.unique(predictions, return_counts=True)).T)
```